# Database delete isSuccess is true but record not deleted

Tags: apex, trigger, database

I've been trying to remove related record called it A before inserting record B on trigger. In the handler i was querying record A by value populated in record B field. When i called result and debug it isSuccess was true but record was still there. If code needed i'll have to recreate it but it was simple query and then Database.Delete

Answer (score -1, accepted):

check the logs are they showing a success for the overall transaction understand even after the delete being success if anything breaks later on everything is rolled
back...

this is what we call Atomicity in terms of Database behaviour

Comment: How to check success for the overall transaction ? Im checking logs cant see any errors.

Comment: It has to be an error in the logs, or something's seriously wrong with the code(like someone has some weird thing setup in the delete trigger or a savepoint)... why don't you share the log and code ....
It seems you are not a dev

Comment: I ran it with allOrNothing false and it worked so at some point transaction rolls back but cannot see where. So i guess your answer is correct.